# Output N in base -10

Tags: code-golf, math, base-conversion

**Challenge:**

In the programming language of your choice, accept an [**integer**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)  as input in base 10, and output it in [**the negadecimal notation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base), which is also known as base -10

**Example algorithm:**

[This is an algorithm taken from Wikipedia to convert base 10 to any negative base in VB.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base):

```vb
Function toNegativeBase(Number As Integer , base As Integer) As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)

    Dim digits As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)
    while Number <> 0
        Dim remainder As Integer= Number Mod base
        Number = CInt(Number / base)

        if remainder < 0 then
            remainder += system.math.abs(base)
            Number+=1
        end if

        digits.Insert(0, remainder)
    end while

    return digits
end function
```

*Obviously, you can use any algorithm, as long as it fulfills the challenge*

**Example inputs / outputs:**

Input:

```vb
12
```

Output:

```vb
192
```

**Another example:**

Input:

```vb
2048
```

Output:

```vb
18168
```

**Rule:**

You must not use any built-in methods that solve this problem that exist in your programming language

This is a **code-golf**, so shortest code wins!

Comment: I think you only want to forbit built-ins that solve this specifiic problem and not _all_ existing builltins.

Comment: Related OEIS: [A039723](http://oeis.org/A039723)

Comment: Whoops you are right @DenkerAffe , fixed.

Comment: Must we handle negative integers as well as positive ones?

Comment: Yup, otherwise I woud say whole numbers @KritixiLithos

Comment: @P.Ktinos Negative whole numbers are as much whole numbers as positive whole numbers. 

Comment: @P.Ktinos I just looked up the definition of “whole number”. It seems that some people refer to (so-called) natural numbers when they say whole numbers while others (including me) refer to integers when they say whole numbers. I guess it is a matter of perspective. I've always been taught that “integer” is a synonym of “whole number”.

Comment: @Toothbrush I guess you are right. I'll edit the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: You should add a negative test case.

Comment: Would `[0, 1, 8, 1, 6, 8]` be an acceptable output for input `2048`?

Comment: @Dennis No, sorry. You should join the digits and output it as an integer.

Comment: That might be worth mentioning in the spec. Your VB code looks like it returns a list.

Comment: @Dennis It's an example of an algorithm used to do the conversion, as some people may not know the way to convert decimal to negadecimal. It's not meant to showcase the way it should be done, and it is not mine, it is taken from wikipedia.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert negadecimal to decimal (and back)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/215797/convert-negadecimal-to-decimal-and-back)

Answer (score 12):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>51</s> <s>45</s> 37 bytes

```js
f=n=>n&&n%10+((k=n<0)+f(k-n/10|0))*10
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=n=>n&&n%10+((k=n<0)+f(k-n/10|0))*10

console.log("12 -> " + f(12))
console.log("2048 -> " + f(2048))
```

Comment: Is there a reference for this algorithm?

Comment: @dfernan I don't really know. This is the result of several golfing iterations, starting with the suggested algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

```
_ì ìAn)¥U}a
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=X+wg7EFuKaVVfWE=&input=MTA=)

#### Explanation

```
_ì ìAn)¥U}a  // Implicit: U = input integer, A = 10
_        }a  // Return the smallest non-negative integer Z that returns a truthy value
             // when run through this function:
 ì           //   Convert Z to a list of its base 10 digits.
   ìAn)      //   Interpret this as a list of base -10 digits and convert to a base 10 integer.
       ¥U    //   Return (the result == U).
             // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Dḅ-10=ð1#
```

This is a brute-force inverse of negadecimal-to-integer conversion.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/ycEerrqGB7eENhsr///83MjCxAAA)

#### How it works

```
Dḅ-10=ð1#  Main link. Argument: n

      ð    Combine the links to the left into a chain and start a new, dyadic
           chain with left and right argument n.
       1#  Repeatedly execute the chain with left argument k = n, n + 1, ... and
           right argument n until the first match is found.
D          Convert k to decimal.
 ḅ-10      Convert the result from base -10 to integer.
     =     Compare the result with n.
```

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, 82 bytes

```
@set/a"d=%1%%10,n=%1/-10-(a=d>>4),d-=a*10
@if %n% neq 0 %0 %n% %d%%2
@echo %d%%2
```

Batch's division truncates to zero, so if the remainder is negative I need to add 1 (and also add 10 to the remainder) to compensate. The digits are then accumulated in `%2` until the result becomes zero.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - 9 bytes

Lel it has the crying emoji in it.

```
fqQijT;_;
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqQijT%3B_%3B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-10%0A12%0A2048&debug=0).

Comment: Why are you crying?? You are on par!

Comment: Because he has the crying emoji on Pyth answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 35 bytes

```
f=lambda n:n and n%10+f(0-n//10)*10
```

Python port of [Arnauld's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105996/61809) algorithm.

Alternatively, for 102 bytes a generic function using the algorithm of the original post:

```
def f(n,b,r=0):
 if n:
  r,n=n%b,n//b
  if r<0:r+=abs(b);n+=1
  return f(n,b,r)+str(r)
 else:return ""
```

Comment: Python doesn't let you declare a default input that depends on another input.

Comment: @xnor It works on my Python installation: `Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44)`.

Comment: How are you calling it? I'm doing [this](http://ideone.com/sRZV4Q) (in 3.5.2). Might you be declaring `k` or `n` elsewhere in the code?

Comment: You were right. I had an `n` previously declared. For some reason, anyway, `k` is not needed as per the current solution. Can you try it?

Comment: Looks good, nice improvement! You don't need the parens around the function call any more.

Comment: Not sure how it comes to work, though, as per Arnauld's algorithm. Why is that `0-n` needs `0` too (`-n` only yields wrong results)?

Comment: The last one I can explain as operator precedence. `-n//10` does `-(n//10)`: negate `n`, then floor-divide by `10`, which rounds down towards negative infinity, not 0. In contrast, `0-n//10` does `0-(n//10)`, which first floor-divides by 10, then negates. For whatever reason, Python treats unary negation with a higher precedence than binary minus. See this [precedence table](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html). I've run into this same situation before in golfing.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>71</s> 67 bytes

```
for(;$n=&$argn;$n=$g-$n/10|0)$d=($r=$n%10)+10*($g=$r<0).$d;echo+$d;
```

or 62 bytes for a port of [Arnauld´s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105996#105996):

```
function n($n){return$n?$n%10+(($k=$n<0)+f($k-$n/10|0))*10:0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
:⁵NµÐĿ%⁵ṚḌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/1qHGr36Gthycc2a8KZD7cOevhjp7///8bGZhYAAA)

#### Background

Converting a list of non-negative from base **b** to integer can be achieved by left-folding by the function **x, y ↦ bx + y**. To convert and integer *to* base **b**, we must simply reverse that function, i.e., find an expression for **bx + y ↦ x, y**.

In Python (and, by extension, Jelly), the result of the modulo operator is always non-negative, so **(bx + y) % |b| = y**.

Also, integer division always rounds down, making sure that if **q = n / d** and **r = n % d**, the equality **n = qd + r** holds. If **s** is the sign of **b**, then **(sx)|b| + y = bx + y**, so **sx = (bx + y) / |b|** and, therefore, **s((bx + y) / |b|) = x.**

#### How it works

```
:⁵NµÐĿ%⁵ṚḌ  Main link. Argument: n

   µ        Combine the links to the left into a monadic chain.
    ÐĿ      Iteratively apply the chain until the results are no longer unique.
            Collect all unique results in an array.
:⁵            Divide the previous return value (initially n) by 10.
  N           Negate; multiply the result by -1.
      %⁵    Take all results modulo 10.
        Ṛ   Reverse the results.
         Ḍ  Convert from base 10 to integer.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), 147 bytes

This is a template language I've been working on.
By no means it is meant to be for golfing.
It even lacks complete basic math, but it allows to write tiny snippets of PHP directly.
This works around that issue.

```
{@setN argv.0}{@whileN}{@setM N}{@php$DATA[N]=($DATA[M]/-10)|0;$DATA[R]=$DATA[M]%-10}{@ifR is lower0}{@incby10 R}{@incN}{@/}{@setD R,D}{@/}{@echoD}
```

This throws a bunch of warnings.
The code is "compiled" into PHP.

Ungolfed, with trash whitespace:

```
{@set no argv.0}
{@while no}
    {@set temp_no no}
    {@php $DATA["no"] = ($DATA["temp_no"] / -10) | 0}
    {@php $DATA["remainder"] = $DATA["temp_no"] % 10}
    
    {@if remainder is lower than 0}
        {@inc by 10 remainder}
        {@inc no}
    {@/}
    {@set digits remainder, digits}
{@/}
{@echo digits}
```

If required, a set-by-step explanation can be added, but I believe that it is pretty straightforward.

---

**Disclaimer**:

The last commit, as of the time of writting this answer, was on 2017-01-07 20:36 UTC+00:00.
This works on commit [140e56ff38f45fa4fd40fd3ec382094e707b1bad](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate/tree/140e56ff38f45fa4fd40fd3ec382094e707b1bad) from 2017-01-06 23:27 UTC+00:00.
That is the version used to run this answer.

The PHP code is available on https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate/140e56ff38f45fa4fd40fd3ec382094e707b1bad/SimpleTemplate.php

I do recommend running this with the last version, but that one works fine for this question.

---

**How to run?**

Create a file with the code and run it like this:

```
<?php

    include 'path/to/SimpleTemplate.php';

    $template = new SimpleTemplate('<code>');

    $template->render(<number>);
```

The value will then be displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 49 bytes

```
d@0="";d@n_:=d[-Floor[n/10]]<>ToString[n~Mod~10];
```

Defines a function `d` taking one integer argument, and returning a string. A recursive algorithm—looks like the same algorithm in [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105996/56178). It does work on negative numbers as well. (It returns the empty string intsead of "0" if the input is 0.) Note for Mathematica golfers: using `±` requires one extra set of parentheses and thus seems not to be any shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
T(в
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/ROPCpv//jQxMLAA) This is not a builtin. It uses builtin base conversion, but not builtin negadecimal conversion.

```
T(в  # full program
  в  # base-10 digits of...
     # implicit input...
  в  # in base...
 (   # negative...
T    # 10
     # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
₀Nτṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigoBOz4ThuYUiLCIiLCIyMDQ4Il0=)

Explanation:

```
  τ   # From base 10 to base
₀     # Ten
 N    # Negated
   ṅ  # Join by nothing
      # Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 68 bytes

```
main(f,a){f&&scanf("%d",&a);f=a?a%10+((f=a<0)+main(0,f-a/10))*10:0;}
```

Instead of printing the resulting number the program just returns it. Obviously this is [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105996#105996), the only difference is that since C isn't an interpreted language I felt like I should make it a full program as opposed to just a function.

Comment: How is it returning it? `f` goes out of scope when the function returns unless I'm being really dumb.

Comment: @abligh You aren't being really dumb, it's just GCC being really dumb. If a non-void function terminates without a return it'll simply use the last assignment.

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, 88 bytes

```
fn g(mut n:i32)->i32{let mut r=n%10;n/=-10;if r<0{r+=10;n+=1;}if n==0{r}else{r+g(n)*10}}
```

This is just a recursive version of the algorithm provided in the question.